# Python login to my cpanel with python

Tags: python, authentication, cpanel

I want to create a script with python that test if my combination (username and password) is correct, but I always get a 401 HTTP response so i think the script can't submit the login data. (the cpanel login isn't a traditional login panel so i will use the demo login panel as our example-site.com) :

```
import urllib, urllib2, os, sys, re
site = 'http://cpanel.demo.cpanel.net/'
username = 'demo'
password = 'demo'
headers = {
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0",
"Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Charset" : "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"}
data = [
("user",username), 
("pass",password), 
("testcookie",1), 
("submit","Log In"), 
("redirect_to",'http://cpanel.demo.cpanel.net/'), 
("rememberme","forever")]

req = urllib2.Request(site, urllib.urlencode(dict(data)), dict(headers))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
if any('index.html' in v for v in response.headers.values()) == True :
 print "Correct login" 
else :
 print "incorrect"
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\cp\cp4.py", line 19, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Access Denied
```

Any ideas to solve the problem and test the login details?

Comment: Site should be `'http://cpanel.demo.cpanel.net/login/'`, I think.

Comment: you can login from that directory also , but you get always the same response

Comment: You're not supposed to POST to the page that you see the form on, you're supposed to POST to the action field of the FORM.

Comment: I think you need to do a POST, rather than a GET.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It is a POST. urllib2 automatically switches when `data` is passed. [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Requests](http://python-requests.org), a much more user-friendly HTTP client library for Python.

```
import requests

url = 'http://cpanel.demo.cpanel.net/login/'
username = 'demo'
password = 'demo'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
}
data = {
    'user': username,
    'pass': password,
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print "Successfully logged in as {username}".format(username=username)
else:
    print "Login unsuccessful: HTTP/{status_code}".format(status_code=response.status_code)
```

Edited to check for HTTP/200, as CPanel does throw an HTTP/401 if the login is incorrect.

Comment: yes it works in this example but in any other host i get this error :/
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\cp\cp6.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = requests.post("http://example-ip:2082", data=logininfo)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`
what i can do ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to POST the login info to `http://cpanel.demo.cpanel.net/login/`

Example using requests (much easier!):

```
import requests
logininfo = {'user':'demo', 'pass':'demo'}
r = requests.post("http://cpanel.demo.cpanel.net/login/", data=logininfo)
if (r.status_code==200):
     print "Correct login"
```